# Need to avoid blocking calls on a service bus architecture.

Tags: python, multithreading, producer-consumer

I am using python and flask.

I am using a microservices built using flask and configured to support a service bus architecture. The microservice is capable of making concurrent service calls and now I need to improve the performance in the service calls being made concurrently.

Initially I used python threading module however it was resulting in blocking calls for main service which invoked it. I would like to know if we try using producer/consumer style of setting this up will that do some good to my requirement.

Basically my main thread should not get stuck indefenitely and that happens when I use join().

Comment: Why are you calling `join()` if you don't want the caller blocked?

Comment: If I don't call join how will the parent know the child isAlive for response.

Comment: That's the `is_alive()`-method for. You can call it in intervals  (e.g. time.sleep(0.1)) within a while-loop  to check if the thread is still alive.